# Авто заполнение формы на сайте и получение данных

Tags: php, c#, mysql, wpf, сервер

В БД есть таблица логинов и паролей от личных кабинетов клиентов (логины и пароли выдаются при заключении договора с клиентом, так что фактически это логин-пароль фирмы но делегированный также клиенту). В каждом личном кабинете присутствуют ознакомительные данные которые нужно спарсить в БД и отобразить в приложении. Сначала предполагалось что админы буду вручную заходить в каждый кабинет и заносить данные через приложение но чем больше клиентов тем сложнее это делать вручную. Вопрос - можно ли программно это осуществить? Например найти на сайте идентификаторы текстбоксов логина и пароля и заполнить значениями из бд а затем через регулярные выражения получать значения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону [Selenium](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium)

Это фреймворк, предназначенный для тестирования, но которым можно успешно выполнить ваши задачи. Он есть под разные языки.

Вы сможете и заполнить поля для входа в систему, и вытащить данные из нужных вам полей/страниц.

Вот [статья](http://autoqa.org/selenium-webdriver-vs/nastrojka-selenium-webdriver-visual-studio.html), описывающая начальную настройку.